# Worklight 6.1 JSONStore call WL.JSONStore.init hangs in Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, init, jsonstore

I meet problem in JSONStore init function in Android. It will hang for about 10 minutes until then the JSONStore gives me the init result callback. This did occur only in Android and iPhone works fine. I can give the reproduce procedure:

1. Install my app in a 'clean' Android, which has not install the app before.
2. Successfully init the JSONStore by my arguemnts (I will attach the code below).
3. Then I re-install my app, note that I did't uninstall it but just replace it with a new build.
4. After replace I'm using the same auth try to init JSONStore, but it hangs....(Maybe will give the result callback at 10 minutes or longer, no error handlers trigger).
5. If a kill the app and re-launch it, then this time the JSONStore init very fast and works fine

I debug the App with inspect and I'm sure this is the problem that WL.JSONStore.init didn't give me result callback that hangs app. I don't know the reason why the first time need to consume so much time. Anyone meet the same issue as me?

```
var options = {password:pscd,localKeyGen:true};
var promise = 
WL.JSONStore.init(data_collection, options).then(function(){
    console.info("init json store successfully!");
    return true;
}).fail(function (errorObject) {
    console.info("init json store failed!" + errorObject);
    return false;
});
return promise;
```

Comment: What happens if you try without the "var promise"?

Comment: It should be the same, because promise is return to outer function to receive async event

Comment: Could you specify which 6.1 version you are using? You can get the full build by going into Eclipse, then going into the About Eclipse -> Installation details and looking at the version for the Worklight Plugin. It should be something like 6.1.0.x-20130512 (just an example).

Comment: Also, are you seeing any errors in Logcat? And could you put your code for data_collection? Are you testing in an Android emulator or with a specific device?

Comment: It would be helpful if you update the question with your logcat log.

Comment: Well, I'm using WL version 6.1.0.01-20140427-1450. I tested it in Real Android Device. Tested some SAMSUNG devices

Comment: I can't see any log from Catlog. It just hangs in the init method and I can't get the result callback. But very tricky thing is: I may got the result in some very long time like after 10 minutes. I just don't know what thing happened during those long time.

Comment: hey dude, do you have any update on this ??

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out the following code in the same 6.1 build that you have, and it is working fine for me on both the Android Emulator and a Nexus 4:

```
    var data_collection = {people : {
        searchFields : {name : 'string', age : 'integer'}
        }
    };
    var pscd = "samplepassword";
    var options = {password:pscd,localKeyGen:true};
    var promise = 
    WL.JSONStore.init(data_collection, options).then(function(){
        alert("init json store successfully!");
        return true;
    }).fail(function (errorObject) {
        alert("init json store failed!" + errorObject);
        return false;
    });
    return promise;
```

The only thing that might be different to your code is what your password or your data_collection variables are. Could you add more details regarding what data_collection is?